# control alignment breaks while show and hiding control

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have implemented UI in angular 7. I have an checkbox control that shows and hide a textarea control beneath it. The problem that I am that whenever the control shows the control on its left is push down.Could somebody tell me what the problem could be ? So here when the sideletter agreement is selected, Side letter details shows up but it pushes down NAV reporting cycle on the left

before
[image]

after
[image]

html code

```
<style>
    label {
        margin-left: 0.5rem;
        vertical-align: middle
    }


    .panel-heading {
        color: black;
        /* background-color: #F5F7F7; */
        border-color: #ddd;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding-top: 5px !important;
        padding-bottom: 5px !important;
    }

    .panel-heading .left-label {
        display: inline-block;
        padding-top: 5px !important;

    }

    .panel-heading label {
        margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    }
</style>



<div class="card" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
    <div class="card-header panel-heading">
        <span class="left-label" style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; ">Fund Terms</span>
        <div class="pull-right" style="padding-right:10px; display: inline-block; vertical-align:middle">
            <label style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle" class="btn btn-primary"
                [ngClass]="{'btn-primary': EditMode, 'btn-default': !EditMode }"><input type="checkbox"
                    [(ngModel)]="EditMode" class="hidden" />Edit Mode</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="Fund">
        <div class="card-body">

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="inputName" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{Fund.Name}}</div>
                    <kendo-dropdownlist *ngIf="EditMode" style="width:100%" [(ngModel)]="Fund"
                        class="form-control  form-control-sm" [data]="Funds" [filterable]="false" textField="Name"
                        [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="Id" (valueChange)="fundChanged($event)">
                    </kendo-dropdownlist>
                </div>

                <label for="inputTitle" class="col-md-2  col-form-label ">Plan Asset Fund</label>
                <div class="col-md-3">

                    <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{Fund.PlanAssetFund === 'true' ? 'Yes' : 'No'}}</div>
                    <label *ngIf="EditMode" style="font-size: 13px;font-weight: normal;cursor: pointer">
                        <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="Fund.PlanAssetFund" style="width: 13px; height: 13px;" />
                        Yes </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="inputTitle" class="col-md-2  col-form-label ">Vehicle Type</label>
                <div class="col-md-3" style="height: 30px">
                    <div>{{Fund.VehicleTypeName}}</div>
                </div>

                <label for="inputOffice" class="col-md-2 col-form-label ">Side Letter Agreement</label>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{Fund.SideLetterAgreement === 'true' ? 'Yes' : 'No'}}</div>
                    <label *ngIf="EditMode" style="font-size: 13px;font-weight: normal;cursor: pointer">
                        <input type="checkbox" #myId checked="checked" (click)="isSideLetterAgreementSelected($event)"
                            value="{{Fund.SideLetterAgreement}}" [(ngModel)]="Fund.SideLetterAgreement"
                            style="width: 13px; height: 13px;" /> Yes </label>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-2  col-form-label ">Investment Manager (Firm)</label>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{Fund.InvestmentManager}}</div>
                    <input *ngIf="EditMode" [(ngModel)]="Fund.InvestmentManager" kendoTextBox [readonly]="false"
                        class="form-control form-control-sm" />
                </div>

                <ng-container *ngIf="isAgreement">
                    <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-2  col-form-label ">Side Letter Details</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{Fund.SideLetterText}}</div>
                        <textarea *ngIf="EditMode" [(ngModel)]="Fund.SideLetterText" style="width:100%" kendoTextArea></textarea>
                    </div>
                </ng-container>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-2  col-form-label ">NAV Reporting Cycle</label>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{Fund.NavReportingCycleName}}</div>
                    <kendo-dropdownlist *ngIf="EditMode" style="width:100%" class="form-control form-control-sm"
                        [data]="ReportingCycle" [(ngModel)]="Fund.NavReportingCycleId" [filterable]="false"
                        [textField]="'Name'" [valuePrimitive]="true" [valueField]="'Id'">
                    </kendo-dropdownlist>

                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="inputName" class="col-md-2  col-form-label ">Fund Currency</label>
                <div class="col-md-3" style="height: 30px">
                    <div>{{Fund.CurrencyName}}</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="inputName" class="col-md-2  col-form-label ">Audit Year End</label>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{Fund.AuditYearEndString}}</div>
                    <kendo-dropdownlist *ngIf="EditMode" style="width:100%" class="form-control form-control-sm"
                        [(ngModel)]="Fund.AuditYearEnd" [data]="AuditYearEnd" [filterable]="false"
                        [valuePrimitive]="true" [textField]="'Name'" [valueField]="'Id'">
                    </kendo-dropdownlist>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-toolbar" style="padding-top:40px;">
                <span *ngIf="EditMode"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-view-all btn mr-3"
                        (click)="Update()">Save</button>

                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your DOM element will keep margin and padding DOM, after you remove it with *ngIf. So try to remove this, and use [ngClass] and add a class with padding and magin when your condition is true and your textarea is visible.

Comment: `ngIf` removes the elements entirely from the DOM, not sure I'd count on this.

Comment: Yes, it's that is true, but if you go with inspect element you'll find that the "removed" element form DOM actually is keeping the margin and padding from box model, and thats you have extra space.

Comment: Hmm, I've not run into that scenario and use it quite extensively.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is using Bootstrap for setting items next to each other. You essentially do this

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">Label</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">Form element</div>
  <div class="col-md-2">Label</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">Form element</div>
</div>
```

leading to something like this

```
+-------+--------------+-------+--------------+
| Label | Form element | Label | Form element |
+-------+--------------+-------+--------------+
```

If one of your columns is increased in height, the whole row will rise accordingly

```
+-------+--------------+-------+--------------+
| Label | Form element | Label | Form element |
|       |              |       | Form element |
|       |              |       | Form element |
|       |              |       | Form element |
+-------+--------------+-------+--------------+
```

This is due to the fact that Bootstrap uses `display: flex` (or `display: inline-block` prior to version 4). Those are all 1-dimensional display settings. In your case you should use `display: table` or `display: grid` for a real 2 dimensional layout

Comment: How and where do I use display: table or display: grid

Comment: @Tom I advise you to find it out for yourself. There are excellent tutorials out there regarding grid. Please don't take this as being unfriendly. I regard finding it out by yourself is the best way to learn.